# Delete document older than One hour is not working in elasticsearch

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and I have an document in elasticsearch and document contain thosands of user views and now I want to delete those view that are older than 3Hours for this purpose I write following query in elasticsearch

```
POST {INDEX}/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "box_views"
          }
        },
        {
          "query": {
            "range": {
              "@created_at": {
                "gte": "now-3h"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I execute this query I receive following error

> {   "error": {
>       "root_cause": [
>         {
>           "type": "parsing_exception",
>           "reason": "no [query] registered for [query]",
>           "line": 1,
>           "col": 66
>         }
>       ],
>       "type": "parsing_exception",
>       "reason": "no [query] registered for [query]",
>       "line": 1,
>       "col": 66   },   "status": 400 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
POST {INDEX}/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "box_views"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@created_at": {
              "gte": "now-3h"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Besides, if you're looking for older documents, I think you should use `lte` instead of `gte`.